# How to read graph from ForkJoin paper by Shipilev?

Tags: java, multithreading, graph

There is the following pdf: http://shipilev.net/talks/jeeconf-May2013-forkjoin.pdf

It contains a graph that I don't understand, attached below. Can anyone provide any help reading it?

[image: Graph In Question That I Don't Understand]

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow must be self contained

Comment: Which means that....?

Comment: You should not point to external resources, everything that's needed to understand the questions should be included in the question directly and not by links.

Comment: Thanks for info, fixed. Now, can you provide any input regarding the graph?

Comment: how to ask questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Title summarizes, problem introduced, to reproduce - N/A, most relevant tags included, proof-read, self contained. What else can I do to satisfy the rules in your opinion?

Comment: What is exactly your question? How to understand Russian Language? How to understand Graphs? How to contact Mr. Shipilev? Ask concrete technical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diagram depicts how balancing works in `ForkJoinPool`.

Vertical lines are threads in the pool. Time is running upside dow. Colour lines that connect threads are task stealings. Every time a thread finds its local task queue empty, it steals some tasks from the local queue of some other thread and you see a line between these two threads.

On early stages (at the top of the diagram) all threads are busy working on their own tasks. But gradually they complete them and start stealing tasks from other threads and the diagram is getting noisy.

The diagram aims to show how `ForkJoinPool` is doing its best to keep all the threads (along with CPU resources) utilised to complete all the tasks as soon as possible.